# go to a page index corresponding to a specific record in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I am working on a web page written in `ASP` and `C#`, where I can add, `edit and delete` records from a `database`. the web page has a `grid view` that contains a `select, edit and delete links` in each row, and the rows are ordered by dates. so my question is:
**How can I insert a new record, and automatically go to its corresponding page? (taking for example the grid view page size is 5)**

> this is a part of the grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSchedulerApplications" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Visible="false" ShowFooter="True" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="sa_ID, sa_ApplicationID"
                            AllowPaging="True" OnRowCommand="grdSchedulerApplications_RowCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditSchedulerApplications" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                                            DataTextField="app_Name" DataValueField="app_Id">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("Application")%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSchedulerApplications" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                                            DataTextField="app_Name" DataValueField="app_Id">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

> And then I have the C# code:

```
protected void grdSchedulerApplications_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
        {
            try
            {
                int saSchdlrID;
                int.TryParse(grdBulkScheduler.SelectedDataKey.Values[0].ToString(), out saSchdlrID);
                DropDownList ddlSchedulerApps = (DropDownList)grdSchedulerApplications.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSchedulerApplications");

                int appID;
                int.TryParse(ddlSchedulerApps.SelectedValue.ToString(), out appID);

                //calling a method from another class to add/update records into database
                object obj = cData.AddUpdateBulkSchedulerApplications(0, saSchdlrID, appID);

                //query returns the automatically incremented ID of newly created record into obj
                if (obj.ToString() != "0")
                {
                    //do some action
                    //here I need to go to the corresponding page Index
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you use SQL paging?

Comment: no, but can you show me a good example please?

Comment: You have to show us what you are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data source returns the rows ordered by the date and you don't modify this order, you need to set the page index and rebind the grid to it's data source:

```
if (obj.ToString() != "0")
{
    grdSchedulerApplications.PageIndex = Int32.Parse(obj) / 5;
    // TODO: Rebind your grid (set the data source and call DataBind())
}
```